# Don't changes layout in android application

Tags: android

I changed in eclipse background of layout and added new view (button).

I started my application but in emulator nothing changed!

What can I make? Mayby it's an Eclipse bug?

Comment: an Eclipse bug? You should post relevant snippet of code

Comment: Eclipse sometimes displays me: "Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. by.idev.android.ownsqlitedb.activity.IdevOwnSqliteDbActivity line 1 Android ADT Problem", but I delete this error and run application again

Comment: " Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. " what is the console content?

Comment: blackbelt, it displays sometimes in tab "Problems"

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this project from internet. Initially it had black background.
I added new View - all was OK.
But after I started changed background - and appeared this bugs

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtInd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

 <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to test the app again, DO NOT click on your app's icon in the emulator. However, select your project, and click on [image]

IF this doesn't work. Try cleaning your project from : `Project` >>> `Clean`